# Error in Mysql running

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql, sudo, password-recovery

Please check the below image and let me know how to stop the terminal or end the process.
This happened after I entered `sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld`.

[image: img_terminal]

Also do inform me about how to reset the password as with `sudo` command. The entered password shows the below error.
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: Can I assume that you just want MySQL to run on its own normally?

Comment: You can assume.